# How to add margins to mobile site (using ProPhoto)

Tags: wordpress, mobile, margins

The website is https://www.alisamesseroffphotography.com/ and the mobile site margins look awful. We use PhoPhoto in Wordpress, and cannot figure out how to add some margins.

Thanks so much!

Comment: @Mike_Messeroff. Read about [Media Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6370690/media-queries-how-to-target-desktop-tablet-and-mobile) and how it works. Or consider some alternatives for your template which respects responsive.

Answer (score 0):

What mobile site?
It's literally the same site.

You need to look at ditching or changing the theme.

As the other answer says, look at  [media queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) : using a media query you can change how the page displays depending on the screen size it is viewed on. For instance, you could use this to add padding to the article-content class to force there to be white space around all the content on the page (but not the navigation or header image) which I think would solve your problem.

I think you should probably change the theme, something based on [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) would do a lot of the styling on a mobile device for you, and would make the navigation work better.